# Generated sql not ok with criteriaBuilder function

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I use spring boot 3

```
Specification<School> specification = (Root<School> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

    Predicate p  = cb.disjunction();
    p.getExpressions().add(cb.function("contains", Boolean.class, root.get("adr"), cb.literal(search.adr())));

    return p;
};
return findAll(specification, page);
```

Sql generated

```
from
    school s1_0 
where
    1!=1
```

Edit same issue with Criteria

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<School> cq = cb.createQuery(School.class);
Root<School> rootSchool = cq.from(School.class);

Predicate p  = cb.disjunction();
p.getExpressions().add(cb.function("contains", Boolean.class, rootSchool.get("adr"), cb.literal(adr)));
    cq.where(p);

List<School> schools=entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: What is your expectation? How your `School` class looks like?

Comment: should be  from schol s1_0 where s1_0 contains(adr);  actually contains is not added to the query

Answer (score 1):

That's by design. Read the Java doc of `Predicate#getExpressions`. It says that changes to the list do not affect the predicate. You will have to build the predicate with `CriteriaBuilder#or` or simply build a predicate with `CriteriaBuilder#isTrue` and pass that to `CriteriaQuery#where`